# Best way to load a uiimage into the uitableviewcell's background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'd like to put a custom uiimage in my uitableviewcell's background but I don't know what is the best way to do it.
One way is to put an iboutlet type uiimage and load the image there. The other way I thought is to create a view and replace the backgroundview. I think the last one is the best but I don't know what is the best option.

On the other hand, I dont know where I should change the background. I thought in the method cellforrow, when I create the cells for the first time, not when I reuse them. What do you think?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you asking about the table view or the table view cell? You have one in your title and the other in your question.

Comment: sorry, uitableviewcell. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method after initializing the cell,Create a imageview with bounds of cell and then add the imageview into it and then set it as the background view of the cell

Use this

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]] autorelease];
```

Comment: I've had problems with this before. I can't remember exactly, but I think that if the table is a part of a `UINavigationView`, then if you come back to the view that has the table after going deeper in the navigation, the background image doesn't show up right away. I don't remember for sure, but definitely make sure you test this well.

Comment: don't you need to put the frame for the imageview?